# How to set Working Precision/ Accuracy global for the entire notebook in mathematica

Tags: numerical-value, precision-and-accuracy

```
F1[r]=((37.3042 - r) (-25.578 + r) (62.8822 + r))/(3000 r)
FindMaximum[F1[r], r]
```

The output is `{0.0345106, {r -> 31.0723}}`.
Then I defined the quantities

```
maxr = r /. FindMaximum[F1[r], r][[2]]
maxF1 = FindMaximum[F1[r], r][[1]]
```

`maxr` gives the value of r at which `F1[r]` is a maximum, and `maxF1` is the value of that maximum.

Now I take the difference between the two ways of finding the maximum, which should be exactly 0, but I got a nonzero contribution.

```
maxF1 - F1[maxr] // N
```

The output I got is `1.38778*10^-17`. How do I change the working precision or accuracy to always make this exactly `0.` in a given notebook?

Comment: `maxr` and `maxF1` seem to have the same definition; is this intentional? Also, what is `maxxf`?

Comment: Ah, I think I understand, and I've edited your question to match, if that's ok.

Comment: yes that is fine now

Answer (score 3):

Each function such as `FindMaximum` has its own settings for precision and accuracy. So, you could for example evaluate

```
FindMaximum[F1[r], r, WorkingPrecision -> 50]
```

for example, and this would use 50 digits of precision during that computation, which in this case seems to be enough to get the result to be exactly `0.`.

Another relevant option is `AccuracyGoal`, which will change the point that is found slightly, but not the precision with which it's located. So, you'd still need to modify `WorkingPrecision`, e.g.

```
FindMaximum[F1[r], r, WorkingPrecision -> 50, AccuracyGoal -> 50]
```

(Another possibly relevant option is `PrecisionGoal`, but usually `Automatic` is good enough.)

But to set these for the entire notebook, instead of in each individual function call, you can evaluate

```
SetOptions[FindMaximum, {WorkingPrecision -> 50, AccuracyGoal -> 50}]
```

and now `FindMaximum[F1[r], r]` will use those options by default. (At least, within that kernel session.)

Hope this helps!